# Fitted curve seems sub-optimal. How to fix this?

Tags: python, matplotlib, scipy, jupyter, curve-fitting

I am trying to fit a curve to a set of points.

I am using `curve_fit` for that. I am calling it without any special parameter values.

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.curve_fit.html

The objective function which I have defined and which I am trying to fit is just some sort of monotonically decreasing function... something like this:

`F(x) = b1 / log(x) + b2 / x + b3 / (x * log(x)) + b4/(x**2) + c`

where

the constants b1,b2,b3,b4,c are all positive.

The red curve is what I am getting from my call to `curve_fit`.

But I feel like it's sub-optimal. I read in the docs that it's doing
LMS optimization but I don't see how the red curve is better than the green
(the green one I drew by hand).

Can I make the call to `curve_fit` so that I get something like the green curve?
Isn't that one more optimal?
Any parameters of `curve_fit` that I can or should tweak?

[image: pic005]

Comment: you need to provide better initial guesses for the parameters with `p0` (default is 1)

Comment: @Stef I noticed that when I have more blue dots (say over 100), I don't have this problem. It's only for cases in which I have just 15-20 blue dots. Is that related to what you say? How do I provide these initial guesses? I was hoping the `curve_fit` to infer them from the dots. I have no idea what the values should look like (numerically I mean).

Comment: can you share the values (blue dots) shown in your image?

Comment: Yeah but my objective function is also not quite that, I scale the X a bit before I apply log and other operations on it. So I am asking more like for some good hints, I can take it over from there and get it working.

Comment: @Stef I just tried with `p0=(1,1,1,0.1,0.1)` and I got a curve which I like much more (closer to the green one). But that was pure guessing from my side. Isn't there a better way? Note that I need to do this curve fitting for multiple sets of blue dots, do I need to manually provide initial `p0` guesses each time?

Comment: hm, when the overall shape of the data is more or less the same and you use the same fitting function every time you could derive some good guesses from theoretical considerations by eg. looking at the asymptotes of your fitting function; if the data shape varies substantially from case to case I don't have any idea though

Comment: No, the shape does not vary really. What varies is the number of blue dots. And when I have a small number of blue dots, a simple call to `curve_fit` is not enough. Seems I need to provide these initial hints via `p0`. My point is... I guess I will need to do it one by one for each set of blue dots that I have providing a different p0 each time.

Comment: or maybe you could first try to fit a simpler function and then derive some guesses for the initial values of the final fitting from these results

Comment: @Stef OK... thanks a lot indeed! I will try something along these lines.